# jsgrid addrow to server using ajax

Tags: jquery, jsgrid

jQuery jsgrid plugin allows to insert a new row to the gridview. Once data is entered click the Plus (+) button on the row to add to the grid. I want to try to save to the server as well along with the current action. How to call ajax webservice when the + button in the new row is clicked?

I can access the "+" button using the class name. and trigger a js function. But want to know if there are any other better options

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the `controller` code in your `jsGrid` definition?

You add an `insertItem` property to the `controller` object. It should be something like:

```
controller: {
     loadData: ... code to load data to grid ....
     ,
     insertItem: function(item) {
        return $.ajax("/api/users/", {
          method: "POST",
          data: { item },
          error: (jqXHR , status, err) => {
              alert("Error: " + jqXHR.responseText");
            },
          success: (result, status, jqXHR) => {
              console.log(result);
          }
     }, 
     ...
```

`item` will contain the new row that you have added. The above assumes you have a backend web service /api/users listening for HTTP POST.

If the web service returns a 200 status code, the grid showing the input fields will close and the row will be in the read mode.  If the return code is other than 200, the grid input row will remain in the data entry mode.